# How can I ignore a determinated file in recursive search?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I was working on a project to list all files and directories and their recursive elements from a path, code of the function:

```
    def recursive_search(path: str) -> "list[str]":
    """get all files from an absolute path

   :param path: absolute path of the directory to search
   :type path: str
   :return: a list of all files
   :rtype: list[str]
   """
    found_files = []
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        raise RuntimeError(f"'{path}' is not a directory")
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, item)
        if os.path.isfile(full_path):
            found_files.append(full_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(full_path):
            found_files.extend(recursive_search(full_path))
    return found_files
```

I call the function like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user = getuser()
    directory = "C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\Desktop\\archivos"
    path = (recursive_search(directory))
```

Its possible ignore a file, for example I want to get all directories and files from "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop", but I  don't want to catch the file "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\desktop.ini", how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be straight-forward here with your example. You can improve it further to get a relative path.

```
for item in os.listdir(path):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, item)
        if os.path.isfile(full_path):
            if not os.path.samefile(full_path, 'C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\desktop.ini'):
                found_files.append(full_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(full_path):
            found_files.extend(recursive_search(full_path))
    return found_files
```